# javascript addEventListener don't add event

Tags: javascript, html, class, oop, events

I have code like below. I made Javascript class named "Car" and in constructor I add event to html "" tag. But this event can't fire.

Could somebody help me?

Thanks,
A.

```js
function Car(model, brand) {

  this.model = model;
  this.brand = brand;

  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('onclick', this.info);
}

// method
Car.prototype.info = function() {
  alert("It is " + this.model);
};

// define cariable
var car = new Car("RX7", "Mazda");

// Invoke method in html
//car.info();

// second way
window.onload = function() {
  var car = new Car("RX7", "Mazda");
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event should be `click` not `onclick`.

To bind the context use `bind(this)` on the event handler function reference.

```js
function Car(model, brand) {
  this.model = model;
  this.brand = brand;

  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', this.info.bind(this));
  //                                                 ^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^
}

// method
Car.prototype.info = function() {
  alert("It is " + this.model);
};

// define cariable
var car = new Car("RX7", "Mazda");

// Invoke method in html
//car.info();

// second way
window.onload = function() {
  var car = new Car("RX7", "Mazda");
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

---

I hope this is just for the Demo purpose, if you want to use this in real project use following code.

```js
function Car(model, brand) {
  this.model = model;
  this.brand = brand;
}

// method
Car.prototype.info = function() {
  alert("It is " + this.model);
};

// define cariable
var car = new Car("RX7", "Mazda");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var car = new Car("RX7", "Mazda");
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', car.info.bind(car));
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank You very much:-) Great answer.
I wanted to do this as "universal" search filter which need not too many places where it is needed to add code. It is why I added events in constructor.
In your first excample, method invokes 2x times after one clisk. What can be a reason?
Second excample work well.

Comment: @arrowman In first example the `Car` constructor is invoked twice, so the event is bound two times on the same element causing the handler to run twice on single click. I'd recommend to use the second example.

Answer (score 0):

@Tushar
Thank You very much. I wouldn't do this wihtout your help :-)

For someone, who wants have everything "more inside" a class, I prepared some changes in @Tushar code.

But I don't know if it is consistent in any programming standard.

```js
function Car(model, brand) {
  this.model = model;
  this.brand = brand;
  
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', this.info.bind(this));
}

// method
Car.prototype.info = function() {
  alert("It is " + this.model);
};


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var car = new Car("RX7", "Mazda");
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>
```